# Gradient of quadratic form

Tags: matrices, derivatives, quadratic-forms, scalar-fields

I am new to linear algebra. I appreciate if somebody helps me to solve this problem. I have a function $f(v)=hvv^Hh^H$, where $h\in \mathbf{C}^{1\times N}$ is a constant vector, $v\in \mathbf{C}^{N\times 1}$ is variable vector, and $H$ denotes Hermitian transpose. I need to calculate $\nabla f(v)$

Comment: Btw, this resource is quite useful for these sorts of queries https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf

Answer (score 1):

For consistency, use column vectors so that both ${\,h,v\in\mathbb C}^{N\times 1}$

Then consider the complex scalar 
$$\phi = h^Tv$$
in terms of which your (real) function is
$$f= |\phi|^2 = \phi^*\phi$$
Since $\phi$ depends solely upon $v$ (and $\phi^*$ upon $v^*$) we can easily find the gradient as
$$\eqalign{
df &= \phi^*d\phi = (\phi^*h)^Tdv \cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial v} &= \phi^*h \cr
}$$
Taking the complex conjugate yields
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial v^*} = \phi h^*
 \implies 
\frac{\partial f}{\partial v^H} = \phi h^H
$$

Comment: Thanks for your help Greg.